# Как достать переменную из функции Python? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, переменные, локальные-переменные

```
entry = Entry(windowApi,width=45,bd=3, textvariable= api)
entry.pack(anchor="w", padx=0, pady=20)
```

данный код находится в функции, для вызова вспомогательного окна
подскажите как сделать чтобы переменная api отображалась и вне функции
Примерно так ⬇

```
        entry = Entry(windowApi,width=45,bd=3, textvariable= api) 
        #⬆ это меню для ввода api
        entry.pack(anchor="w", padx=0, pady=20)
    print(api) # и тут выводился введённый мною api
```

На сайте нашёл подобный вариант решения⬇, но как адаптировать под своё окно не знаю

```
i = 10
def a():
    global i
    i = 2
a() # i вместо 10 равно 2.
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: pp.py                                                                                                                                                         
       global api
       entry = Entry(windowApi,width=45,bd=3, textvariable= api) # это меню для ввода api
       entry.pack(anchor="w", padx=0, pady=20)                                                                                              ss.py                                                                                                                                                         
        print(api)

Comment: Andrey, для того чтобы дополнить\отредактировать свой вопрос - нажмите кнопку `Править`. Пожалуйста, внимательно прочитайте первый комментарий к вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk


def func():
    entry = tk.Entry(windowApi, width=45,bd=3, textvariable=api) 
    entry.pack(anchor="w", padx=0, pady=20)


def getResult():
    result = api.get()
    print(result)


windowApi = tk.Tk()
api = tk.StringVar(value="qwerty12345")
func()
button = tk.Button(windowApi, text='OK', command=getResult)
button.pack()

windowApi.mainloop()
```

Переменная api объявляется как StringVar, после чего она будет видна за пределами функции. Получить из нее значение можно методом get().
Возможно это поможет в решении вопроса...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: поправил свое решение...

Answer (score 0):

К сожаленью, первый комментатор прав, вы почти не показали хоть часть вашего кода, за который можно зацепиться. Но если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то, то, что вам нужно сделать — это добавить в начало функции выражение `global *variable*`:

```
api = ''
def func():
    global api
    api = "qwerty12345"
    entry = Entry(windowApi,width=45,bd=3, textvariable= api) 
    entry.pack(anchor="w", padx=0, pady=20)
print(api)
```

Тем самым вы объявляете, что переменная не ограничивается всего лишь в функции, и изменяется для всего кода.

Comment: Я попробовал, но увы команда print выводит в терминал вот это "PY_VAR0". Если есть возможность напишите мне на почту abobusandrobus@gmail.com и я вышлю вам код целиком. Буду благодарен за помощь